# Modify cell attributes using field from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to use a simple table nested in a cell to show a graph on my elections result page.

```
<td>
    <%: result.candidateName %>
    <table style="border:0; padding:2px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:50px; border:0; height:15px; color:Blue; padding:0; font-size:75%;"><%: result.percentWon %>%</td>
            <td style="background-color:Blue; width:400px; border:0; height:15px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

What I need to do is change the width figure in the cell style (set to 400px now) to be 4*result.percentWon, but I cant figure out how to put Aligator tags in the middle of the style string.

Yes I'm a noob  (o:  Can anyone school me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `<%: ... %>` where-ever you want:

```
<td style="background-color:Blue; width:<%:4*result.percentWon%>px; border:0; height:15px;"></td>
```

Comment: Hot diggidy damn.  Intelisense doesn't work, but it builds magnificently.  Thnaks

Comment: @Juspar: This is a known issue with the editor; it cannot handle deeply nested IntelliSense contexts.